# How can I add more functionality to a get; and set; in Xamarin forms by removing the "=>" and replacing with a code block for each?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, syntax

I would like to change this code:

```
public string Height
{
   get => (string)GetValue(HeightProperty);
   set => SetValue(HeightProperty, value);
}
```

How can I change the code to not use the `=>` and add in for example some more lines of code before and after the things that happen with the get and set?

Comment: note that this is a pure C# question, it has nothing to do with Xamarin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can open code blocks after `get` and `set`:

```
public string Height
{
   get {
       // do something
       return (string)GetValue(HeightProperty);
   }
   set {
       // validations, etc...
       SetValue(HeightProperty, value);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use curly brackets.

```
public string Height
{
   get
   {
      <your code>
      return (string)GetValue(HeightProperty);
   }
   set
   {
      <your code>
      SetValue(HeightProperty, value);
      <your code>
   }
}
```